# Movement of elements in GEF editor not working

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

I am currently building an editor with Eclipse GEF. It is possible to add new parts via the editor and rename them.

However I have a little problem with the moving of the elements. When dragging them with the mouse they are not moved when I release the mouse and the element doesn't collide with another one.
The positions of the elements are stored in an `EMap` (the model is made with EMF). Changes in the view are saved with the `put` method of the map.

While going through it with the debugger I noticed that the command is executed, but the view is not refreshed yet.

I added an adapter to the model, but its `notifyChanged` is not called from the system.

```
public class ViewAdapter implements Adapter { 
    @Override 
    public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) { 
        refreshVisuals(); 
    } 
}
```

The `ViewAdapter` is registered in the activate method of the `EditPart`.

What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are working with a map the normal `Adapter` interface won't work, because it only listens to adds or removals of map entries.

If you want to listen on changes of map elements, you should use an `EContentAdapter` instead:

```
public class ViewAdapter extends EContentAdapter {
    @Override
    public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {
        refreshVisuals();
        super.notifyChanged(notification);
    }
}
```

It is important that you call the super method so the notifications of the map entries are forwared to the map itself.